# What is the best way to manage dll libraries?

Tags: .net, dll

I am having difficulties to manage all the dlls used in different projects. we have like 15 different application running in our company and they are pointing to different libraries.

Now we are converting all these asp.net applications + Libraries to .NET 4.0 and possibly rewriting some libraries with Entity Framework.

I am wondering what is the best way to organize these libraries?

1. Should we create one solution, categories the libraries into different projects and add those project into one solution?
2. Should we create one project and categorize the libraries into different folders and build as one library?

if we use the 2nd approach would it be any performance issue?
What is the most efficient approach performance wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all libraries that are shared between multiple applications:

- Group the related libraries together in an own solution. Which means that you'll get one or solutions for the libraries only.
- Then use an own [nuget](http://nuget.org/) [hosted service](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) to handle the dependencies. By doing so you can 
  easy manage dependencies in your applications. Its just a question of invoking "update-package" in the package manager console.

By using nuget you can also include templates and such showing how to use each library and automatically modify app/web.config to add the required keys.

Comment: This is what I done in company where I work, and it is great solution for "lib" folder clutter.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, we are definitely looking into it. But the most trouble i am facing is from my co-worker who wants to create one big library which has all the libraries added. so when we create any new application we just have to point to one dll rather than pointing to specific libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised the word 'NameSpace' didn't pop-up in your question, because it is one good way to put order in your code if you have a great number of Class / enum / modules / ...
Personnaly i do use NameSpaces (and i nest them sometimes), which allows me to avoid some name conflict issues, and permit also a more convenient use of intellisense.

Comment: Namespaces probably didn't come up since it's a fundamental thing that everyone uses.

Comment: you mean, just like 'using hosted service' or 'grouping in a solution' ? Yes, quite true.